# please help, python table file find max value

Tags: python-2.7

please help
I'm a beginner to python programming and my problem is this:

I have to make a program which first reads a text file like this one->

```
A a 1 2 (line one)

A b 3 5 (line two)

A c 9 1

B d 2 4

B e 9 2

C r 3 4
...
```

and find out: for each First Value (A, B, C, ...), which second value (a, b, c, ...) has max (third value)*(fourth value) (1*2, 3*5, ...) value.

that is, in this example the result should be b, e, r.

And I need to do it 1) without using dictionary class and saving each data

or 2) devise a class and object and do the same thing.
(actually I have to make this program twice by using either methods)

What I'am really confused about is... I made this program first by using dictionary, but I have no idea how to do it with any of those two certain methods mentioned above.

I did this by making `dictionary[dictionary[value]]` format and (saving each line's data), and found out which one has max value for first value. 
How can I do this not on this particular way?

Especially is it even possible to do this on method 1)? (without using dictionary class and saving each data)

thank you for reading my question
I'm really just beginning to learn about this programming and if any of you could give me some advice it would be really appreciated

here is what I've done so far:

Comment: Show us what you have so far, and where you're having trouble. If you understand how objects work than show us the ones you've written and how they don't function. If you don't, there is plenty of stuff out there outlining Python's object model. Good luck.

Comment: thank you :):) I hope what I've done is right!

Answer (score 0):

The below code works by storing the maximum values and doing comparisons with the values currently being read from the file. This code is not complete as it does not *intentionally* handle instances where two of the products are the same and it also does not handle an edge case that you should be able to find using your example inputs. I've left those for you to complete.

```
max_vals = []
with open('FILE.TXT', 'r') as f:
    max_first_val = None
    max_second_val = None
    max_prod = 0
    for line in f:
        vals = line.strip('\n').split(' ')
        curr_prod = int(vals[2]) * int(vals[3])

        if vals[0] != max_first_val and max_first_val is not None:
            max_vals.append(max_second_val)
            max_first_val = vals[0]
            max_prod = 0

    if curr_prod > max_prod:
        max_first_val = vals[0]
        max_second_val = vals[1]
        max_prod = curr_prod
```

Comment: thank you so much ♡♡ I couldn't have made this program without your help thank you!! :>  ♡